# KineticJS Animation by updating customized shape

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I now have a customized Shape, and this shape is controlled by one global variable. Thus I assume I just need to change this global variable due to `frame.time`, erase the old shape, and create the new one.

But however it seems not working. The following is the simplified code.

```
<script>
  var toControlShape;
  var myDrawFunction(context) {
    // toControlShape will be used here. 
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({...});
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var myShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
      drawFunc: myDrawFunction,
      ...
    });

    layer.add(myShape);
    stage.add(layer);

    var animation = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
      toControlShape = someFunction(frame.time);
      myShape.remove();
      myShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: myDrawFunction,
        ...
      });
      layer.add(myShape);
    }, layer);

    animation.start();
  };
</script>
```

The shape displays properly as its initial state. But there is no animation.

I am pretty new to Javascript and HTML5. So there might be a lot of anti-patterns in this code. Pointing out them to me is also appreciated.

The complete code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4R843/) on jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your doing it wrong. From the docs:

- "Kinetic.Animation which modifies the shape's position with each
  animation frame."

So i think you should stop remove the shape and instead just update the shape. Then it should probably the animation part work for you.

html ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Strath</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="kinetic-v4.1.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="fiddle.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


<div id="PureHTML5"></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

js ---

```
    var segsToSkip = 0;
      var triangle;
      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "PureHTML5",
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


        /*
         * create a triangle shape by defining a
         * drawing function which draws a triangle
         */
        var box = new Kinetic.Shape({
          drawFunc: myDrawFunction,
          stroke: "white",
          strokeWidth: 8
        });
        var bbox= new Kinetic.Rect({
            x:10,
            y:10,
            width:10,
            height:10,
            fill: 'green'
        });

          triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(context) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(10, 10);
          context.lineTo(20, 80);
          context.quadraticCurveTo(30, 10, 26, 17);
          context.closePath();
          context.stroke();  

        },
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      }); 
        layer.add(bbox);
        // add the triangle shape to the layer
        layer.add(box);
        layer.add(triangle);
        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);

         var animation = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
            console.log(frame.time);
             var newSegsToSkip = Math.round(frame.time / 200);
                  triangle.setX(newSegsToSkip);
         triangle.setDrawFunc(function(context) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(newSegsToSkip, 10);
          context.lineTo(newSegsToSkip+20, 80);
          context.quadraticCurveTo(30, 10, 26, 17);
          context.closePath();
          context.stroke();  
                 });
             }, layer);



         var animation2 = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
            var newSegsToSkip = Math.round(frame.time / 200);
            if (newSegsToSkip == segsToSkip) return;
            else {
                segsToSkip = newSegsToSkip;
                box.remove();
                box = new Kinetic.Shape({
                  drawFunc: myDrawFunction,
                  stroke: "black",
                  strokeWidth: 8
                });
                layer.add(box);
            }
        }, layer);
        animation.start();
           animation2.start();
      };

var myDrawFunction = function(context) {
    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;
    var width = 200;
    var height = 200;
    var radius = 20;
    var dashedLength = 6;
    var segsToDraw = 58;

    context.beginPath();

    context.drawDashedBox(x, y, width, height, radius, dashedLength, segsToSkip, segsToDraw);

    context.closePath();
    //   context.stroke();  
    //this.fill(context);
    this.stroke(context);
}

var CP = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
CP.drawDashedBox = function(x, y, width, height, radius, dashedLength, segsToSkip, segsToDraw) {
    // init
    var env = getStratEnvForRCBox(x, y, width, height, radius, dashedLength, segsToSkip, segsToDraw);

    // 'right'->'upper-right'->'down'->'bottom-right'->'left'->'bottom-left'->'up'->'upper-left'->'right'->...
    while (env.segsToDraw > 0) {
        console.log('drawing direction: ', env.direction, 'segsToDraw:', env.segsToDraw);
        env.putToConsole();
        if (env.direction == 'right') {
            env = drawDashedLineNew(env, x + width - radius, y + height, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'bottom-right';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'upper-right') {
            env = drawDashedArcNew(env, x + width - radius, y + radius, radius, 0, Math.PI / 2, dashedLength, this);    
            env.direction = 'left';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'down') {
            env = drawDashedLineNew(env, x, y + height - radius, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'bottom-left';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'bottom-right') {
            env = drawDashedArcNew(env, x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, 3 * Math.PI / 2, 2 * Math.PI, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'up';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'left') {
            env = drawDashedLineNew(env, x + radius, y, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'upper-left';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'bottom-left') {
            env = drawDashedArcNew(env, x + radius, y + height - radius, radius, Math.PI, 3 * Math.PI / 2, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'right';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'up') {
            env = drawDashedLineNew(env, x + width, y + radius, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'upper-right';
        }
        else if (env.direction == 'upper-left') {
            env = drawDashedArcNew(env, x + radius, y + radius, radius, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, dashedLength, this);
            env.direction = 'down';
        }
    }
}

function getStratEnvForRCBox(x, y, width, height, radius, dashLength, segsToSkip, segsToDraw) {
    var direction = 'right';
    var startX, startY;
    if (direction == 'down') {
        startX = x; startY = y + radius;
    } else if (direction == 'right') {
        startX = x + radius; startY = y + height;
    } else if (direction == 'up') {
        startX = x + width; startY = y + height - radius;
    } else if (direction == 'left') {
        startX = x + width - radius; startY = y;
    }
    var env = new Environment(startX, startY, 'gap', 0, direction, segsToSkip, segsToDraw);
    return env;
}

function drawDashedLineNew(env, endX, endY, dashedLength, context) {
    var dx = (endX - env.x), dy = (endY - env.y);
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    console.log('drawing line: angle =', angle, ' , ', env.gapOrDash, ' =', env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw);

    var fromX = env.x, fromY = env.y;
    // deal with remining
    // we start loop from a fresh dash
    if (env.gapOrDash == 'dash') {
        // check if we need to skip
        if (env.segsToSkip > 0) {
            env.segsToSkip --;
        } else {
            context.moveTo(env.x, env.y);
            context.lineTo(env.x + env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw * Math.cos(angle), env.y + env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw * Math.sin(angle));
            // check if we quit
            env.segsToDraw --;
            if (env.segsToDraw == 0) return env;
        }

        // a full gap
        fromX = env.x + (env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw + dashedLength) * Math.cos(angle);
        fromY = env.y + (env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw + dashedLength) * Math.sin(angle);
    } else if (env.gapOrDash == 'gap') {
        fromX = env.x + env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw * Math.cos(angle);
        fromY = env.y + env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw * Math.sin(angle);
    }

    var length = (endX - fromX) / Math.cos(angle);
    if (endX - fromX == 0) length = Math.abs(endY - fromY);
    var n = length / dashedLength;
    var draw = true;
    var x = fromX, y = fromY;
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x += dashedLength * Math.cos(angle);
        y += dashedLength * Math.sin(angle);
        if (draw) {
            // check if we need to skip
            if (env.segsToSkip > 0) {
                env.segsToSkip --;
            } else {
                context.lineTo(x,y);

                // check if we quit
                env.segsToDraw --;
                if (env.segsToDraw == 0) return env;
            }
        } else context.moveTo(x, y);
        draw = !draw;
    }

    // deal with remaining
    if (draw) {
        // check if we need to skip
        if (env.segsToSkip > 0) {
            env.segsToSkip --;
        } else
            context.lineTo(endX, endY);
    }
    env.x = endX;
    env.y = endY;
    draw ? env.gapOrDash = 'dash' : env.gapOrDash = 'gap';
    env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw = dashedLength - (endX - x) / Math.cos(angle);

    return env;
}

function drawDashedArcNew(env, x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, dashedLength, context) {
    var points = [];
    var n = radius * Math.PI * 2/ dashedLength;
    var stepAngle = Math.PI * 2 / n;

    // deal with remaining
    var angle = Math.asin(env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw / 2 / radius) * 2;
    if (env.gapOrDash == 'dash') {
        var angle = Math.asin(env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw / 2 / radius) * 2;
        points.push({
            x : (Math.cos(startAngle) * radius) + x,
            y : - (Math.sin(startAngle) * radius) + y,
            ex : (Math.cos(startAngle + angle) * radius) + x,
            ey : - (Math.sin(startAngle + angle) * radius) + y
        });

        startAngle += stepAngle + angle;
    } else {
        startAngle += angle;
    }

    var draw = true;
    while(startAngle + stepAngle <= endAngle) {
        if (draw) {
            points.push({
            x : (Math.cos(startAngle) * radius) + x,
            y : - (Math.sin(startAngle) * radius) + y,
            ex : (Math.cos(startAngle + stepAngle) * radius) + x,
            ey : - (Math.sin(startAngle + stepAngle) * radius) + y
            });    
        }

        startAngle += stepAngle;
        draw = !draw;
    }

    // deal with the remaining
    var endX = (Math.cos(endAngle) * radius) + x;
    var endY = - (Math.sin(endAngle) * radius) + y;
    //console.log('drawing arc: end-x:', endX, ',end-y:', endY);
    if (draw) {
        points.push({
            x : (Math.cos(startAngle) * radius) + x,
            y : - (Math.sin(startAngle) * radius) + y,
            ex : endX,
            ey : endY
        });
    }
    env.x = endX;
    env.y = endY;
    draw ? env.gapOrDash = 'dash' : env.gapOrDash = 'gap';
    env.remainingLengthFromLastDraw = dashedLength - radius * Math.sin( (endAngle - startAngle) / 2) * 2;

    for(p = 0; p < points.length; p++){
        //console.log('draw arc seg: from(', points[p].x, ',', points[p].y, ') to (', points[p].ex, ',', points[p].ey, ')');
        // check if we need to skip
        if (env.segsToSkip > 0) {
            env.segsToSkip --;
        } else {
            context.moveTo(points[p].x, points[p].y);
            context.lineTo(points[p].ex, points[p].ey);

            // check if we quit
            env.segsToDraw --;
            if (env.segsToDraw == 0) return env;
        }
    }

    return env;
}

function Environment(x, y, gapOrDash, remainingLengthFromLastDraw, direction, segsToSkip, segsToDraw) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gapOrDash = gapOrDash;
    this.remainingLengthFromLastDraw = remainingLengthFromLastDraw;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.segsToSkip = segsToSkip;
    this.segsToDraw = segsToDraw;
}
Environment.prototype.putToConsole = function() {
    //console.log('Environment:');
    //console.log('x:', this.x, ',y:', this.y, 'direction:', this.direction);
    //console.log('toSkip:', this.segsToSkip, 'toDraw:', this.segsToDraw);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't find any APIs to allow you redraw/update a shape. Thanks

Comment: A 'pure' kineticjs shape is very easy todo a animation with and just update for example the position with shape.setX(newx) in the animation frame. Since you have a custom shape ju must update the shape within the drawFunc, if you want more than just move it but you should keep the shape and not do remove in each frame. So split out the box = new Kinetic.Shape to load, and then access the shape.getDrawFunc() and set a new drawfunc with shape.setDrawFunc(drawFunc) in the animation frame.

Comment: @qinsoon, even if I think that you should not use the remove but use update, I got your code to work locally using kinetic 4.1.2 version